# Close opinionated questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, opinion-based

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878344/how-good-is-php-performance) looks like an opinion with very little research details. Why wasn't this closed for this exact reason? Which btw might also be considered an opinion.

Comment: you'd have to ask all the people who over the years visited it and didn't cast a close vote.

Comment: My opinion: no one cares about that question enough  and hence no votes (including VTC)... An upvote once a year is not really indication of a question that is frequently visited by people who even can moderate  the site (and one needs 3+ people with 3K+ rep to visit first even to consider to vote to close it)...

Comment: Thank you for bringing attention to the question - It has now been closed.

Comment: Most questions from 2008 and 2009 get very little attention because the search engines (for whatever reason) refuses to include them in search results.

Comment: @PeterMortensen maybe there's some way we can lie to the search engines about the age of the post?

Comment: "This question looks like an opinion" - not at all actually. It is a question *asking for* opinions. Which is the actual close reason. Besides old questions, you can wonder how many close-worthy questions slip by in a day among the thousands asked. We do the best we can under the circumstances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many old questions lurking around that don't meet today's site standards. They are definitely closable, including this one. People just haven't necessarily gotten to it yet.

Trying to use Meta on an individual-question basis for this is inefficient, especially as there is not really any general principle you need to ask about. Instead, there are organized efforts to review these decisions specifically, for example the [Close Vote Review](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room which has its own [web site for policy guidance](https://socvr.org/).

Comment: "*There are many old questions [...] People just haven't necessarily gotten to it yet.*" just to back up with some numbers: right now there are 22.8 *million* questions on the site which are still open. [See search here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+is%3Aq). Going through all of them may take a bit of time.